# How to get different top margins in different pages of TOC in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents

I need to put 2 inch top margin in the first page of TOC; and 1 inch of top margin in the subsequent pages.

I tried to do this by putting section breaks within the TOC. However, any time I do 'update field' of TOC; the section breaks within the TOC are gone.

Any idea how I can achieve my objective? I am using MS Word 2010.

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: @Sathya-MS word 2010